# Importing function from other file in clojure

Tags: clojure

How can i import a function in closure? Suppose i have two files:

```
test.clj
test2.clj
```

I want to use the function from `test2` in `test`.

I have tried the following in `test`, but this is not working:

```
(namespace user :require test2)
```

How am a able to import a function in another file?

Basically want to do `from lib import f in python

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In file `test.clj`:

```clj
(ns test
  (:require [test2 :as t2]))

(defn myfn [x]
  (t2/somefn x)
  (t2/otherfn x))
```

In the above example, `t2` is an alias for the namespace `test2`. If instead you prefer to add specified symbols from the namespace use `:refer`:

```clj
(ns test
  (:require [test2 :refer [somefn otherfn]]))

(defn myfn [x]
  (somefn x)
  (otherfn x))
```

To refer to all public symbols in the namespace, use `:refer :all`:

```clj
(ns test
  (:require [test2 :refer :all]))

(defn myfn [x]
  (somefn x)
  (otherfn x))
```

Answer (score 3):

Your namespace syntax is a bit off. I usually refer to [this cheat-sheet](https://gist.github.com/ghoseb/287710/#file-ns-cheatsheet-clj) when I need a reminder.

I *think* the following is the syntax you are looking for.

```clj
;; In test.clj
(ns test
  (:require [test2 :refer [some-symbol-to-import]]))
```